# Ordenar caracteres de un string en vb

Tags: vb

Estoy intentando organizar el texto almacenado en una variable. Por ejemplo: si la variable trae el string *ABAB*, que el resultado sea *AABB*.
Estoy usando este código pero no me trae más de una vez el mismo caracter:

```vb
Dim i
Dim tmpVar As String
Dim found As String

'Obtener Cadena a Ordenar
strinvertir = Text1.Text
' Valor decimal ASCII de la "A" a la "Z"
For i = 65 To 90



'Buscar la letra
found = InStr(1, strinvertir, Chr(i), vbTextCompare)
'Si se encuentra agregar a variable
If found Then
tmpVar = tmpVar & Chr(i)
End If
Next i
'Regresar resultado aun textbox
Text2.Text = tmpVar
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta con que uses la función `OrderBy` que te retornará una coleccion(IEnumerable) de caracteres(Char). Y luego juntas las colección con `String.Join`

```
Dim entrada = "ABAB"
Dim ordenado = String.Join("", entrada.OrderBy(Function(x) x))
Console.WriteLine(ordenado) 'AABB
```