# ordenar caracteres de un srtring en vb

Tags: string, vb, caracteres, vectores

Estoy intentando organizar el texto almacenado en una variable
ejemplo: si la variable trae el string"ABAB" EL RESULTADO SEA AABB.
ESTOY USANDO ESTE CODIGO PERO NO ME TRAE MAS DE UNA VEZ EL MISMO CARACTER
Dim i
Dim tmpVar As String
Dim found As String

'Obtener Cadena a Ordenar
strinvertir = Text1.Text
' Valor decimal ASCII de la "A" a la "Z"
For i = 65 To 90

'Buscar la letra
found = InStr(1, strinvertir, Chr(i), vbTextCompare)
'Si se encuentra agregar a variable
If found Then
tmpVar = tmpVar & Chr(i)
End If
Next i
'Regresar resultado aun textbox
Text2.Text = tmpVar

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [ordenar caracteres de un srtring en vb](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/609598/ordenar-caracteres-de-un-srtring-en-vb)